# Local folders mapped to container volumes are not synced

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created a container using Docker build/run and another using Docker-Compose, I tried to map both to a folder under Users directory, however the files created in the container are not displayed in the local folder. Why?

PS: My host is running Windows 10 with Docker Toolbox